# Capybara NoMethodError: undefined method `visit' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Thank for response.
I getting error in application [Git application with the error](https://github.com/itsNikolay/error)

```
Failures:

  1) Page pages page creation with invalid information should not create a page
     Failure/Error: before(:each) { visit new_admin_page_path }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<Page:0x00000005094bb0>
     # ./spec/requests/page_request_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Page pages page creation with invalid information error messages 
     Failure/Error: before(:each) { visit new_admin_page_path }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<Page:0x000000051671f0>
     # ./spec/requests/page_request_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.21 seconds
14 examples, 2 failures
```

What I've missed ?

Comment: https://github.com/itsNikolay/error/blob/master/spec/requests/page_request_spec.rb  (All files are in github repo )

Comment: I found your problem (see below), but you'll have other problems once you fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I cloned your repository and ran the spec. The problem is that you are using the term `page` for two different things, the Capybara page (`subject { page }`) and your model with the name `Page` (which you also name `page`). Those two names conflict, which is why rspec is complaining that there is no method `visit` for `#<Page:0x00000005094bb0>`.

To solve this just rename the page you create in the initial `let`:

```
let(:mypage) { Factory.create(:page) }
```

That will avoid the conflict by naming your page model `mypage` instead of `page`.

There are other issues however. Your user factory does not use a sequence for assigning emails, so you get a validation error because it says the email is already taken.

I changed your user factory to this:

```
sequence(:email) { |n| "abc#{n}@example.com"}
factory :user do
  email
  password "foobar"
  password_confirmation "foobar"
  ...
```

That fixes the validation error, but you now get another error. In the line in your first spec, you should be checking that `count` does not change on the *class* `Page`, not the *record* `page` (or `mypage`).

So change that to:

```
expect { click_button "Create Page" }.not_to change(Page, :count)
```

This will *still* leave you with errors, because you also do not have any `create` action for your `PagesController`. From what you wrote, it seems like the information is invalid so it should not even get to this action. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here so I'll leave the rest for you to figure out.

Comment: Updated my answer, you have a few things to fix.

Comment: Ugh, thank you!  This is not the first time this has bitten me but sometimes you can just look past the obvious.  My next project won't have a PagesController :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you recently upgraded to Capybara 2.0 & your integration tests were working with previous version of Capybara, you may try renaming requests directory to features. Check http://www.codelearn.org/blog/how-to-make-old-integration-tests-work-with-capybara-2-0

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` (in your `Spork.prefork` block):

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
```

Comment: I would go through shioyama's suggestion, and if none of that helps, post a new question - the solution is probably quite specific to your setup.